# Path is not available in PHP exec or shell_exec

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell, centos6

I've been trying and searching about a small issue I have in our php application. We use a which to find the full path of a program, however it returns with

```
which: no bla in ((null))
```

on Centos, on our own debian boxes it works just fine. I've figured out since then that (obviously) the PATH is not available in the shell from PHP. But what I can't find out is why that is the case. I've replaced the command with all sorts of commands to find out what the environment is in which I run in.

If I run an echo $PATH I actually see the directories I've set in the .bash_profile. If I run echo $SHELL I know I am using bash, if I run whoami I found out I am not the apache user but a different user, whom I changed the .bash_profile for. As I've read there's a difference between shells, so I thought it might not load the .bash_profile so I've also added the export PATH to the .bashrc.

I can get it to work with a change in the code, I could replace the which, but I am just genuinely interested in why this is not working on this centos configuration. I've now added an export PATH in the exec function before the which and it works, and should also work on other systems, but still I think it shouldn't be necessary.

Anyone know what could cause this behaviour?

Comment: Sounds like that `$PATH` environment variable is not exported to child processes. There is a difference between just defining such a variable for the current process and exporting it so that it will get inherited by child processes. That would explain why an `echo $PATH` executed in the current shell process sees the value, since `echo` is a shell-builtin, whilst processes started from there do not. `bash` offers the command `export $PATH` for that. You would have to place it right after where the content is assigned to your `$PATH` environment variable.

Comment: In both .bash_profile and .bashrc I've defined the path and export it:

    `# .bash_profile

    # Get the aliases and functions
    if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
 . ~/.bashrc
    fi

    # User specific environment and startup programs

    PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin

    export PATH`

Comment: In who's home directory are those files? and under what user account are your scripts executed?

Comment: They are under a specific user account, so it's not apache or www-data. I don't want to give the actual name. I'm also not totally sure how our hosting company has set it up. When I do a whoami in the PHP script, it's the user I also log in with and whom I set the path in the bash_profile and the bashrc file. Those files as well as the webapplication are stored in that users home folder.

Comment: That is a _hosting companies_ system and you have permission to execute shell scripts there? Then most likely the issue is not the `$PATH` variable, but that your script is inside a `chroot` container. Which perfectly makes sense from a security point of view. That could also explain why those bash profile scripts are not applied. But anyway, if that is a _hosting companies_ system, then why do you ask _us_? Ask _them_! They will know!

Comment: Actually they don't, I have asked them already. This is a hosting company that basically runs servers, but we just get access, so we don't need to maintain the servers ourselves, but we do get all the access rights to deploy our software. To clarify further, I am not really running a script, I am running a command from php. But I'll check into that chroot you mention, I am not really sure what that means. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Let me see if I understand the chroot correctly, if the user would have been chroot-ed to their home for example, would they be able to execute normal commands from /usr/bin and /usr/sbin or would that be impossible too, since I've done that, and they seem to work fine.

Comment: That depends on the setup. The user could not access the physical localtions in the file system that are outside his jail. But folders may be mapped inside, specifically to allow access to for example standard utilities. However if those systems are exclusive for you, then this is not very likely.

Comment: Not sure if I got that right now. If your call from php does _not_ open a shell, but executes some executable right away, then it won't start an extra shell before. In that case the question of that executable will be found in the `PATH` depends in the variables value set in the calling scope, so the php script.

Comment: If the user is chrooted should I be able to change my directory to outside my home? Because I just tested and I can cd to /usr/bin (for example).

Comment: You cannot escape a jailroot, no. That is the whole point of the jail root. _But:_ as said before it is very common to map certain parts of the outside file system into your jail root, so that you can use it. This is a bit like mounting, from inside the jail you cannot really see any difference.